# How can I detach the SORM Instance?

Tags: scala, sorm

The definition of the used database is an Instance object, right? How can I make it "attachable"?

Why? It would be nice to change the used database on tests for example. I tried some implicit definitions, but no success...

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you imply under "attachable". Could you be more specific? Concerning how testing SORM instances go you can always check out how it's being done in SORM's tests itself

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
case class Artist ( name : String, genre : Genre )

object Artist {
  def save(name: String, genre: Genre)(implicit Db: Instance) {
    ...
    Db.save(...)

  }
}
```

And then when I need it, I define the implicit Instance to be used as database.

Comment: It looks like the `object Db extends Instance...` is messing with your head. The thing is you're not obliged to have instances as singletons you're absolutely free to declare them as classes or use the `Instance` class directly. The "object Db" approach is just a general use-case. Also, it very much looks like this companion-object approach is a gross overcomplication - you can simply have the instance as a local variable of the class or a function you're using it in.